# Getting values from tables based on description in another table

Tags: sql, while-loop, cursor

I have a table `Values_to_find` with description to find values in tables (approximately 10k rows). Example:

```
Table_name  Column_name Row_id
table1      2           13
table8      9           22
...
```

`Table_name` has values: `table0`, `table1`, ... `table9` (these tables are temporary in my database, but to show example I wrote names like for normal tables)
`Column_name`: from 0 to 9
`Row_id` from 0 to 100

I want to get all values which source is describe in `Values_to_find` table. How can I do in optimal way?
I was thinking about `while` loop or `cursor`, but inside them I would use creating `@query` variable like:

```
DECLARE @query VARCHAR(500)
SET @query = '
    SELECT ['+@Column_name+']
    FROM #'+@Table_name+'
    WHERE Row_id = '+@Row_id
```

And then I would use `EXEC (@query)` or sth like this to get return value from `@query`. But is it optimal? I don't know. Do you have any ideas how can I do this in a good way?

Answer (score 0):

If I understand the question correctly, to yield the result of dynamic query you can use combination of table variable and the sp_executesql stored procedure. It will look something like this:

```
DECLARE @result as table(Col1 varchar(200))
DECLARE @query VARCHAR(500)
SET @query = '
    SELECT ['+@Column_name+']
    FROM #'+@Table_name+'
    WHERE Row_id = '+@Row_id

INSERT INTO @result EXEC SP_EXECUTESQL @qry
SELECT * FROM @result
```

You can also use OPENROWSET, following [this approach](http://sqlserverplanet.com/tsql/insert-stored-procedure-results-into-table), which will require admin permissions to set it up.

Comment: No, my question was: "How can I get all values which source is described in Values_to_find table in optimal way?" I would have to do 10k operations in case of using `EXEC @query`. And I am wondering if it is good and maybe there is another better approach to get specified data.

Comment: Oh, sorry for that. I'm still not sure I understand entirely, but since you have to build 10k queries dynamically and then execute them, I don't think you can do anything else than looping through a cursor. More optimal way could require rethinking the whole scheme you use to store the data, something that I would encourage.

Comment: I'm afraid that rethinking the whole scheme is not possible, because tables `#tableX` are taking 1:1 from Excel files. I've hope that there is maybe some smart solution to get specified data from these tables, but if it's not, then I stayed with exec queries.